# setActiveItem doesn't work from panel sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a list in tab panel and i added `onItemDisclosure` which supposed to switch to an into page (inside the tab panel).
The `setActiveItem` does not work, and the error I got is that: `[undefined]` is not a function.
Code:

```
Toolbar.views.listPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.List,{
         id:'mylist',
         store:ListStore,
         itemTpl: '<div class="stores"><b>{name}</b><br/><p style="font-size:small">{address}{distance}Km</p></div>',
         //grouped:true,
         onItemDisclosure: function(){
                //Ext.Msg.alert("closure works!");
                //Toolbar.views.detailPanel.update();
                //alert(Toolbar.views.detailPanel);
                Toolbar.views.Searchcard.setActiveItem(Toolbar.views.detailPanel,{type:'slide',direction:'left'});
         }

     });
```

The panel to switch to:

```
Toolbar.views.detailPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
id:'detailpanel',
tpl:'Hello!'
});

Ext.reg('searchcard', Toolbar.views.Searchcard);
Ext.reg('listPanel', Toolbar.views.listPanel);   
Ext.reg('detailPanel', Toolbar.views.detailPanel);
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: that's awesome. Usually when I tell people that they ignore me. :) It's most appreciated and part of what makes SO great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're referencing the class not the instance of the Searchcard. You have to reference it using a component query.

Generally it follows this way:

```
masterComponent.getComponent('your_component_itemID');
```

Or you can use panel.query(selector)

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel-method-query

Really instead of just hacking it through have a look at this article:
http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the response.
Could you please give me more specific example?
I didn't understand.
 In addition i drilled the link you gave me and It's quite different from my code, I don't want to change my whole code..

Comment: in your onItemDisclosure function
You would need to have some code like 
Ext.view.Viewport.getComponent('panelAttachedToComponent').getComponent(..) and drill down
or you can do something like
thisPanel.setActiveItem(Ext.ComponentQuery.query(theSelector))
selector can be an xtype
thisPanel is a reference to your parent panel, not the class type, but the instance of that class.

I really recommend reading that article, you will just give yourself a bigger headache in the end hacking the code together.